# Functions fire in wrong order

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, mapkit

I'm programming a UISearchBar with an accompanying UITableView to suggest relevant locations using Apple's NLP kit, Mapkit, etc. The objective is that when the user selects one of the rows, that the map will zoom to the latitude and longitude. However, I've run into a problem where when one tries to select a suggested row, the function searchBarShouldEndEditing() executes before didSelectRowAt() hiding the tableView and not allowing the user to select the row. Can I specify which function I want to execute first in this instance?

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
    searchBar.delegate = self     
    searchTableView.delegate = self
    searchTableView.dataSource = self
    searchCompleter.delegate = self
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let searchRequest = MKLocalSearchRequest(completion: mapItems[indexPath.row])
        let search = MKLocalSearch(request: searchRequest)
        search.start { (response, error) in
            let coordinate = response?.mapItems[indexPath.row].placemark.coordinate
            self.zoomToLatestLocation(with: coordinate!)
            self.searchTableView.isHidden = true
        }
}    

func searchBarShouldEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool {
    print(1)
    self.searchTableView.isHidden = true
    return true
}
```

Comment: When ever the search bar goes out of focus `searchBarDidEndEditing` would be called. Don’t hide table view inside `searchBarDidEndEditing` instead place it in `didSelectRow`

Comment: @user1046037 That would work except I need to hide the tableview when I select a view other than my tableview and search bar as well

Comment: Would it be difficult to add touch gesture recogniser to the other views to do it ? And same applies to the buttons as well. The reason I say that is because this is the order things would be fired in.

Comment: "Can I specify which function I want to execute first in this instance?" No. Just the opposite: it's up to you to slot your code into the right place so that things happen correctly.